# fb.ui returning post_id in callback but does not actually post

Tags: javascript, facebook, feed

I'm trying to use fb.ui in order to open a dialog so my users will be able to post on their friends wall.
i'm trying the most basic sample that facebook has:

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
<p id='msg'></p>

<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

Everything looks to work great, the callback is called and i see the post_id but when i go into facebook i cant see the actual post on my friend's wall..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong..
My app was in sandbox mode and therefore i did get the post_id but the app didn't really post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify "to" attribute inside the object "obj" to post it to your friends' wall. The attribute value should be the uid of your friend on whose wall you want to post.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/